# How can I fetch datas from API and redirect a page on hooks.server.js?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I get JavaScript heap out of memory.

this is my hooks.server.js

```
import { _, locale } from "svelte-i18n";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').HandleFetch} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  const languageCookie = event.cookies.get("language") ?? "en";

  await locale.set(languageCookie);
  event.cookies.set("language", languageCookie);
  event.locals.language = languageCookie;

  const apiFetch = await event.fetch("/api/global");
  const apiFetchJson = await apiFetch.json();
  console.log(apiFetchJson);

  if (event.locals.language != apiFetchJson.language) {
    return new Response("Redirect", {
      status: 303,
      headers: { Location: `/${languageCookie}` },
    });
  }

  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}
```

[when i try to fetch on handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcnTW.png)

I want to make language system with url. When i fetch datas from API, i send the language to API. API sends datas related the language to me. And i use cookies to save language and svelte-i18n. When i click the button on the header (change language), i want to change the language on url. So i set the language with cookies, and in hooks.server.js, when there is a request, check the language on API and language on cookie.
if both languages are different, then redirect to language on cookie for url
like http://localhost:5173/tr to http://localhost:5173/en

Actually I tried `handleFetch` too. Yes, the fetch is valid in `handleFetch`. But it doesn't redirect another page. `handle` redirect another page but it doesn't fetch.